# I want to do mouse clicking after size of specific log-file being changed. (within PowerShell)

Tags: windows, powershell

Powershell question. I want to do mouse clicking after size of log-file being changed. In link Mouse Click automation with powershell (or other non-external software) there is example how to use New-Object SystemDrawingPoint that helps for the second part of my question. But I don't know how to "connect" these two actions: log-file changed + mouse click ensue.

I tried connect SystemDrawing Point with IO.FileSystemWatcher but no luck.

```
Function Register-Watcher {
param ($folder)
$filter = "Process.log"
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
IncludeSubdirectories = $false
EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$x = 515
$y = 625
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object 
System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
sleep -Seconds 02
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}}

Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName "Changed" -Action $changeAction
}

Register-Watcher "C:\Users\User\AppData\Temp\3.0\Logs"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In a nutshell I want next thing:                                                                       
    function watch($command, $file) {
      if($file #changed) {
      #run MOUSE CLICKING (Object - FileSystemWatcher)
      }
}

Comment: In my specific case:  mouse (automatically presses position I specify) on button of software - starts collecting data (log-file changes) - after log-file changed I want that mouse continue (automatically specified position) on another button. In that chain everything is fine except I don't know how to connect WATCH FOR FILE with ensueing MOUSE CLICKING. Cheers.